# 000webhost "0" value at username

Tags: android-studio

I connected my android studio program to a database with a login and register function. 
Everytime I register my profile the username value is always "0" in the database.
Here's the code:

Register Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, age, password, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Register Request

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest{

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://animotradings.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("age", age + "");
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {

    return params;
}
```

}

Register.php File

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id52837_animotradings", "password", "id52837_animotradings");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);?>
```

Comment: It would be best if you show your attempts to fix the problem, such as dumped values from the PHP script.

Comment: As per [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#114598), `$_POST` is only set by PHP if you have the right content-type in your request.